# task_vector vs task_struct concept

Tags: kernel

I am having diffulty understanding how number of processes are limited by the size of `task_vector`

I am reading this page, https://www.tldp.org/LDP/tlk/kernel/processes.html

> each process is represented by a task_struct data structure (task and process are
>   terms that Linux uses interchangeably). The task vector is an array of
>   pointers to every task_struct data structure in the system.
>
> This means that the maximum number of processes in the system is limited by the size of the task vector; by default it has 512 entries.
>   As processes are created, a new task_struct is allocated from system
>   memory and added into the task vector. To make it easy to find, the
>   current, running, process is pointed to by the current pointer.

From above, I understood the concept of task_struct and that it is a data structure of process, and that task_vector is array of pointer to every task_struct. But on the following image, I don't understand what is `task_vector`. It also says `it has 512 entries`, does that mean there can only be maximum `512` processes?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

That document seems to be dated from around 1999; indeed it states on its front cover that *this book is based upon the current, stable, 2.0.33 sources*. So although many of its concepts may still be valid, the numerical constraints such as a limit of 512 tasks (processes) are almost certainly not.

The `task_vector` is not shown in your diagram. The starting point is a `task_struct`, shown in part on the left-hand side.

Comment: is there anywhere where i can find task_vector in diagram?

Comment: It's a list of task_struct pointers.